# Capture only hashchange events not resulting from anchor clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hashchange

I am trying to use Javascript to emulate the CSS `:target` pseudo-class so as to capture all events that result in an element on page being targeted. I've identified 3 trigger events:

1. `window.location.hash` already targets an element of the same ID on initialisation
2. An anchor targeting the element is clicked
3. The `hashchange` event is fired independently of the above (for example via the `window.history` API)

Scenario 2 is important as a distinct case since I would want to invoke the `click` event's `preventDefault`. The simplified code for this scenario follows:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*=#]', function filterTarget(clickEvent){
    $(this.hash).trigger('target', [clickEvent]);
});
```

The problem comes when trying to implement scenario 3:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function filterTarget(hashChangeEvent){
    $(this.hash).trigger('target', [hashChangeEvent]);
});
```

If a `target` handler *doesn't* cancel the native behaviour for scenario 2, it will be triggered again when the native behaviour causes the resulting `hashchange` event. How can I filter out these edge cases?

**POST-SOLUTION EDIT:**

roasted's answer held the key — handle a namespaced hashchange event, then unbind and rebind the handler based on logic handled inside the click handler and its preventDefault. [I wrote up the full plugin here](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/5916651).

Comment: Could you give an example of how a user might use the system you're describing?

Comment: @SamuelReid I'm working on a rich single-page web app with a strong focus on progressive enhancement: all interactions and navigations that are conceptually feasible for user agents without Javascript are handled with form elements, and (most often) links — a lot of the time hashes are used to navigate to or reveal elements within the page. But when Javascript is applied, I would often want to interrupt those events and replace native behaviour.

Comment: @SamuelReid for a specific example: there is something like a 'footnotes viewer' that displays extensive citations. Native behaviour is to simply jump to the citation in question, but enhanced behaviour opens up a modal interface to better interact with citations and source material references holistically. I want people to be able to share permalinks to footnotes, but if JS is available I still want the 'footnotes viewer' where possible.

Comment: So you need it so that if scenario 2 does not cancel the default event, scenario 3 will run?

Comment: @SamuelReid no — I'm saying that a hashchange resulting from a click should not trigger another target event, because in holistic terms that targeting event has already been captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand it, you don't want the hashchange event to be fired if an anchor tag is clicked. You could then set your logic using namespaced events:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hDSxq/show/)

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*=#]', function (clickEvent) {
    filterTarget(clickEvent,this);  
    $(window).off('hashchange.filter').on('hashchange.tmp', function () {
          $(this).off('hashchange.tmp').on('hashchange.filter', filterTarget);
    });
});
$(window).on('hashchange.filter', filterTarget);

function filterTarget(event,elem) {
    $(elem?elem.hash:window.location.hash).trigger('target', [event]);
    //you could filter depending event.type
    alert(event.type + '::'+ (elem?elem.hash:window.location.hash));
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I want — the event nesting and chaining threw me but now that I've got time to work through it, I'm convinced namespace filtering is the solution. I'm going to extend the captured `clickEvent`'s `preventDefault` to re-instate the `hashchange` handler and post results when I've got it sorted.

Comment: Sorry for not awarding the bounty sooner — I was waiting til I found the time to srite up my completed script — but the point is your solution works absolutely beautifully and the result is doing wonders for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if the click is setting the hash with the fragment anyway, just throw away duplicates in the hash change event:

```
onhashchange=function(e){
  if(e.newURL == e.oldURL ){return; }
 //do your normal hashchange event stuff below:

};
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

this fixes cascade issues no matter what invoked the change.

Comment: `hashchange` deals with this implicitly, in that the theoretical event where `e.newURL == e.oldURL` wouldn't trigger a `hashchange` (there's no change). In the context of the actual `hashchange` event I do want to stop (where the `e.newURL != e.oldURL`), I need to know whether the root cause was a link click or not — which would already have triggered a `target` event.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use mousedown instead of click, if you're going to be calling preventDefault on it. Then presumably the hashchange would not be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The challenge lies in not firing `target` once based on the click event and then again based on `hashchange`: In effect, I only want `target` to fire as a result of a `hashchange` if that `hashchange` is not itself the result of a `click` (which will already have triggered the `target` event once).